# Service in a Thread vs Thread in a Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am trying to build a application which takes values from sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope) and stores them in files, which I believe is CPU-intensive. 
So my question is **whether I should make a thread in `MainActivity` and start my Service or should I make a thread in my `MyService`** and do all the necessaries?
I was reading [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics) and it said:

> If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors.

So which one is the better option for me?

Comment: Reading values from sensors and storing them to disk is IO intensive but shouldn't be CPU intensive unless you are processing the data before storing it.

Comment: Are you saying reading values from sensors won't be CPU intensive? And I am calculating the user's velocity too before storing it (but that could also be done by the server, if I feel it is getting heavy for devices to compute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much i understood your question, you need to manage a thread in your service. 
As android says about Thread

```
- if it is destroyed by android in middle due to low memory, then android will not guarantee to restart it again. That means user lost his half work.
```

So

1> Because your work need to be restarted if it gets an unexpected error. so you should put your thread inside the service. and start thread again if stopped.

2> If you put your thread in your activity it will be lost as activity finishes. But opposite in service. Service is high priority task for android. if it is destroyed while performing its job, in the middle by Android due to low memory scenario. Then android will make sure that it will restart your service, if you have returned `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand()`.

3> `Thread` - is not a component of android, so android will not take thread priority into consideration while killing an application due to low memory.

4>`Service` - is a component of android, so it has priority levels to be considered while destroying an application due to low memory.

Comment: Welcome Nikhil :)